# how can I debug PredictionIO queries?

Tags: predictionio

is it possible to deploy **pio engine's query server** with debug options? I want to debug my queries via **intellij idea**.

I was reading that link https://predictionio.apache.org/resources/intellij/ but it doesn't work for me. I actually want to debug queries to http://localhost:8000/queries.json